# Weird behavior of UITableView data source methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

I want to create a `UIViewController` class with default implementations of the standard tableview datasource methods (`-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, `-numberOfRows`, etc.).

I want to create a custom drop down list.

Here is a detail explanation of my problem:
I define `MyDropDownListController` class which implements `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols with `UITableView` ivar called `table`.

Then, I define custom a config method:

```
-(void)initDropDownListWithItems:(NSArray*)items andAddToView:(UIView*)view
{
    dropDownItems = items; //data source array of items to display in list
    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height + 1, view.frame.size.width, 140)];
    [view addSubview:table]; //add my table to view
    [table setDataSource:self];
    [table setDelegate:self];
    [table reloadData];
 }
```

Then I define `-numberOfRowsInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` etc.
After this, in some other `UIViewController` class (*where I want my drop down list*) I have this:

```
dataSource = @[@"first", @"second", @"third"];
MyDropDownListController * list= [[MyDropDownListController alloc] init];
[list initDropDownListWithItems:dataSource andAddToView:someViewInThisController];
```

After launching the app, when showing this list I get weird exceptions like:

> -[_UIParallaxDimmingView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16500c70

As you see datasource methods are not called for `MyDropDownListController` but for some other strange things.

These messages can be a little different:

> [UIBarButtonItem tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent

and so on.

I hope you see the problem.
It seems datasource methods are not called for `MyDropDownListController` as I stated here:

```
[table setDataSource:self];
```

but for some other stuff.

Comment: Could you be setting the table's data source again somewhere in your code? Did you implement the required data source methods in `MyDropDownListController`?

Comment: @BlackRider No I just set them first time in this `initDropDown` method. Yes I said about it `Then I define numberOfRowsInSection: and cellForRowAtIndexPath and etc.`

Comment: Very odd. Does the `[table reloadData]` call inside `initDropDownListWithItems` succeed?

Comment: @BlackRider This problem appears even if I doesn't call `[table reloadData]`

Comment: @BlackRider I remove this call from the post in order not to mislead. As I understood problem with self in those method? Because instead of it method receivers are some other unknown objects

Comment: I'd still be interested to hear if that particular call succeeds. If it does, then the problem appears later on (i.e. the delegate gets replaced, or something similar).

Comment: @BlackRider Ok I tried. Call to [table reloadData] succeeds. And after it I now got an exception: `[_UIParallaxDimmingView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: @BlackRider "(i.e. the delegate gets replaced, or something similar)"I  think the problem here but I cannot understand why?

Comment: there's a way to investigate that, if you're willing to spend a few minutes. Subclass `UITableView`, and use that custom subclass in your code. In that custom table view, override `setDataSource:`. Put a breakpoint there. See who calls it, and what object is passed to it. If someone overrides the data source, this is how you can find out that.

Alternatively, create a symbolic breakpoint for "setDataSource".

Comment: @BlackRider Ok thanks!I will try now and inform you

Comment: @BlackRider I test this. `setDataSource:` called only once. The most weird thing I discovered: numberOfRows is called successfully and returns the correct number and then I got the excpetion described above in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I think the problem is that your list is released with ARC.  Delegate is a weak reference, so once your method is finished it notices that there are no more references to list and deallocates it.  Make `list` a class variable and the problem should go away.

Comment: @BlackRider I put log messages in heightForRow, cellForRow, numberOfRows abd right after call to reloadData. I got next: 1. `numberOfRows called` then message after reloadData and then crash

Comment: @Putz1103 THANKS MAN! It really helped.I think you should post this as an answer in order I can accept it. As i understood all local variables are weak by default? Can you post an aswer with detailed explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that your view controller that has the table as a class variable is being deallocated because it's reference count is 0 at the end of the function.  When you do something like:

```
{
dataSource = @[@"first", @"second", @"third"];
MyDropDownListController * list= [[MyDropDownListController alloc] init];
[list initDropDownListWithItems:dataSource andAddToView:someViewInThisController];
}
```

At the end of the function ARC goes through and marks memory as reusable if it's no longer referenced by anything.  You are referencing the controller as the delegate for the tableview, but delegate is a weak reference and is not counted by ARC.  So the reason you are getting the unrecognized selector is because ARC marks the memory location for re-use, then the OS re-uses it by putting new objects there.  Then your table calls it's delegate (which is still a valid object thanks to the OS refilling the memory) and you get an unrecognized selector error.  If you were not creating objects at the point when this occurs then you would be getting a `bad access` error that could be traceable with NSZombies.

Comment: Thanks.But I didn't understand what you mean by this: "class variable"? In Objective-C I know only class methods. May be you mean local variable?

Comment: A variable defined inside `@interface` (whether it be a property or just an iVar) are class variables (at least in my nomenclature).  Anything defined inside a function (method) is a local variable (local meaning it will go away at the end of the function).